# Maximum column and row sum of matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I take an input of a matrix

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([input().split() for _ in range(3)], dtype=np.int)

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Now I want to display the largest sum. It can be in either columns or rows.

For example in this:
row 3 has maximum sum 24

So my output will be:
row 3 24

Comment: print('row {} {}'.format(np.argmax(np.max(l, axis=0)), axis=0),  np.max(np.max(l, axis=0))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);

rowSum = np.sum(x, axis=1)
colSum = np.sum(x, axis=0)

print("row {} {}".format(np.argmax(rowSum)+1, np.max(rowSum)))
print("col {} {}".format(np.argmax(colSum)+1, np.max(colSum)))

# output:
# row 3 24
# col 3 18
```

See

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html