# list index out of range in python function

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that gets the sum of the highest row,and the sum of the highest column in a matrix and add them toegether.

My function that loops threw each colum is giving me a "list index out of range error" for some reason

```
def max(input1,input2,input3):
  newArray= list(input3)
  seq =newArray
  num = input1
  num2 = input2
  max_row = 0
  max_column = 0
  avg = len(seq) / float(num)
  out = []
  last = 0.0

  while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg
  for i in out:
      # print(sum(i))
      if sum(i) > max_row:
        max_row = sum(i)
  # print(max_row)
  for i in range(0,len(out)):
     maxCols = 0
     sumCols = 0;

    #  print(out)
     for j in range(0,len(out[0])):
          print(i)
          sumCols = sumCols + out[j][i]
          if sumCols > maxCols:
             maxCols = sumCols
  # print(out)
  # print(maxCols)
  return maxCols + max_row
  # return seq


print(max(3,3,{3,6,9,1,4,7,2,8,9}))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(max(3,3,{3,6,9,1,4,7,2,8,9}))
  File "main.py", line 27, in max
    sumCols = sumCols + out[j][i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There's debugger in your IDE. Try to use it. Error message contains more than enough information to find a problem.

Comment: Why do you provide your array as a set, with {}.. print(max(3,3,[3,6,9,1,4,7,2,8,9])) should be better, no ?

Comment: A previous [solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840726/maximum-column-and-row-sum-of-matrix-in-python)

Comment: I am trying to accomplish it with a set

Comment: Will not bring in extra dependencies like numpy

Answer (score 0):

Set will remove the duplicate values, thus your input3 become [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9] after first step of max() function, which is not a 3x3 matrix any more.
Try use list or tuple instead of set in your input3

Comment: I did search and orginally see numpy as an option, However I cannot use anymore libraries

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Numpy for this task. It contains Matrix/Array objects which greatly simplify your task.

```
import numpy as np
```

Define your matrix using `np.matrix()`, then change it to `np.array()`. You could define it with an array straight up but with the Matrix object, you can write out your values in a string format, whereas Array takes a list of lists which can get confusing.

I propose the `matrix_max()` function which takes in the array and iterates over the rows and columns separately. I have given it a name different to `max` because (1) it is the name of a built-in Python function and (2) we need it anyway :)

As you can see, the `for` loops iterate over the rows first, then the columns (which is the same as the rows of the transpose matrix). The `max` function here is checking the new row/column sum against the existing highest, and finally returning the sum of both.

```
def matrix_max(array):

    max_row_sum = 0
    for row in array:
        max_row_sum = max(max_row_sum, sum(row))

    max_col_sum = 0
    for col in array.transpose():
        max_col_sum = max(max_col_sum, sum(col))

    return max_row_sum + max_col_sum
```

Use the function on your example matrix:

```
m = np.matrix('3,6,9;1,4,7;2,8,9')
a = np.array(m)
print(matrix_max(a))
```

The answer printed out is 44.

Comment: @RomaneGreen Is there a reason Numpy is unsuitable? It is a very powerful and popular Pythonian module.

Answer (score 0):

`sumCols = sumCols + out[j][i]` → `sumCols = sumCols + out[i][j]`

if we regard `out` as a 2-dimension table, `i` is its first dimension and represents the row index, and `j` is its second dimension and represents its column index. you made a mistake exchanging them.

also, the pythonic way is as the following:

`sumCols += out[i][j]`

Comment: Adding some explanation might help others.